# Difference between 負担 and ロイヤルティ

Tags: grammar, word-choice

Could you please help me to understand the difference between **負担｛ふたん｝** and **ロイヤルティ**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ロイヤルティ is *royalty*, the money that must be paid typically to a patent owner, a copyright holder, etc. This is a pure technical term, so see the English Wikipedia article for details.

負担 is much more common, and in financial contexts it refers to a share of money you have to pay (for whatever purpose). 負担 also means *workload*, (psychological) *burden*, etc.

> - この橋の建築費用は、国が30%、県が70%を負担した。
> - 税金の負担 tax burden